# Best Way to Simulate Logic Gates in C?

Tags: c, cpu-architecture

Hi I was wondering if anyone would be able to explain to me what is the best path to take if I wanted to simulate logic gates in a c program? 
Lets say for example I create a program and use command line arguments

```
AND GATE
[console]% yourProgram 11001010 11110000
<console>% 11000000
```

If anyone could explain to me what the best route is to start with, I would greatly appreciate it. This is the code I have so far...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
        if( argc >= 3){
                int result = atoi(argv[1])&&atoi(argv[2]);
                printf("Input 1 is %d\n",atoi(argv[1]));
                printf("Input 2 is %d\n",atoi(argv[2]));
                printf("Result is %c\n",result);
        }
        return 0;
```

Comment: `...Result is %d...` maybe a good start? and `&&` changed to `&` ?

Comment: C has built-in bitwise operators - AND: `&`, OR `|`, XOR `^`, NOT `~`.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) has a good article covering the bitwise operations

Comment: atoi converts a string to an int. The string is supposed to be in decimal  notation, and obviously your program should deal with arguments as binary numbers, not decimal ones.

Comment: What you need is bitwise AND, not logical AND.

Comment: Take the type of gate as input .Also, implement the suggestions in the comments above.

Comment: Doing a bitwise and on atoi(argv[1]) and atoi(argv[2]) won't help because atoi assumes the string passed in is a decimal number and not a binary number.  Changing atoi to strtol with a radix of 2 should help.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that printing the result won't work the way it is either because it will print the decimal number - the result needs to be converted back to a binary string before printing it: itoa with a base of 2 might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the comment suggesting basic corrections, if you want to make it a bit more useful and flexible, you could calculate the `most significant bit` and then use that to format a simple binary print routine to examine your bitwise operation.

The primary concepts are taking the input as a string of binary digits and converting them to a number with `strtoul` (base 2), and then following `&`'ing the inputs together to obtain `result` it is just a matter of computing how many bytes to print out and whether to format a single byte into nibbles or simply separate multiple bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* BUILD_64 */
#if defined(__LP64__) || defined(_LP64)
# define BUILD_64   1
#endif

/* BITS_PER_LONG */
#ifdef BUILD_64
# define BITS_PER_LONG 64
#else
# define BITS_PER_LONG 32
#endif

/* CHAR_BIT */
#ifndef CHAR_BIT
# define CHAR_BIT  8
#endif

char *binstrfmt (unsigned long n, unsigned char sz, unsigned char szs, char sep);
static __always_inline unsigned long msbfls (unsigned long word);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if ( argc < 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input. usage: %s b1 b1\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* input conversion and bitwise operation */
    unsigned long b1 = strtoul (argv[1], NULL, 2);
    unsigned long b2 = strtoul (argv[2], NULL, 2);
    unsigned long result = b1 & b2;

    /* variables to use to set binary print format */
    unsigned char msb, msbmax, width, sepwidth;
    msb = msbmax = width = sepwidth = 0;

    /* find the greatest most significant bit */
    msbmax = (msb = msbfls (b1)) > msbmax ? msb : msbmax;
    msbmax = (msb = msbfls (b2)) > msbmax ? msb : msbmax;
    msbmax = (msb = msbfls (result)) > msbmax ? msb : msbmax;
    msbmax = msbmax ? msbmax : 1;

    /* set the number of bytes to print and the separator width */
    width = (msbmax / CHAR_BIT + 1) * CHAR_BIT;
    sepwidth = width > CHAR_BIT ? CHAR_BIT : CHAR_BIT/2;

    /* print the output */
    printf("\n Input 1 : %s\n", binstrfmt (b1, width, sepwidth, '-'));
    printf(" Input 2 : %s\n", binstrfmt (b2, width, sepwidth, '-'));
    printf(" Result  : %s\n\n", binstrfmt (result, width, sepwidth, '-'));

    return 0;
}

/** returns pointer to formatted binary representation of 'n' zero padded to 'sz'.
 *  returns pointer to string contianing formatted binary representation of
 *  unsigned 64-bit (or less ) value zero padded to 'sz' digits with char
 *  'sep' placed every 'szs' digits. (e.g. 10001010 -> 1000-1010).
 */
char *binstrfmt (unsigned long n, unsigned char sz, unsigned char szs, char sep) {

    static char s[2 * BITS_PER_LONG + 1] = {0};
    char *p = s + 2 * BITS_PER_LONG;
    unsigned char i;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        p--;
        if (i > 0 && szs > 0 && i % szs == 0)
            *p-- = sep;
        *p = (n >> i & 1) ? '1' : '0';
    }

    return p;
}

/* return the most significant bit (MSB) for the value supplied. */
static __always_inline unsigned long msbfls(unsigned long word)
{
    if (!word) return 0;

    int num = BITS_PER_LONG - 1;

#if BITS_PER_LONG == 64
    if (!(word & (~0ul << 32))) {
        num -= 32;
        word <<= 32;
    }
#endif
    if (!(word & (~0ul << (BITS_PER_LONG-16)))) {
        num -= 16;
        word <<= 16;
    }
    if (!(word & (~0ul << (BITS_PER_LONG-8)))) {
        num -= 8;
        word <<= 8;
    }
    if (!(word & (~0ul << (BITS_PER_LONG-4)))) {
        num -= 4;
        word <<= 4;
    }
    if (!(word & (~0ul << (BITS_PER_LONG-2)))) {
        num -= 2;
        word <<= 2;
    }
    if (!(word & (~0ul << (BITS_PER_LONG-1))))
        num -= 1;

    return num;
}
```

**Example Output**

```
$ ./bin/andargs 11001010 11110000

 Input 1 : 1100-1010
 Input 2 : 1111-0000
 Result  : 1100-0000

$ ./bin/andargs 1100101011110000 1111000011001010

 Input 1 : 11001010-11110000
 Input 2 : 11110000-11001010
 Result  : 11000000-11000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. (for AND operation):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    if( argc >= 3){
        int i=0;
        printf("1st i/p = %s\n2nd i/p = %s\n",argv[1],argv[2]);
        for (i=0; argv[1][i]!='\0'; i++){   //this assumes there are 2 inputs, of equal size, having bits(1,0) as its digits
            argv[1][i] = argv[1][i] & argv[2][i];    //modifies argv[1] to your required answer
        }
        printf("Answer: %s\n",argv[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In function ‘main’:
error: invalid operands to binary & (have ‘char *’ and ‘char *’)
             argv[1] = argv[1] & argv[2];    //modifies argv[1] to your required answer

Comment: Sorry, just a bit of correction. I did not test it.

Comment: It should be `argv[1][i] & argv[2][i]`. We need to "and" them character by character. Sorry that I missed it. @ace

Comment: Your answer is still wrong. Try testing it and you'll see why. (Or try reading it, it should be obvious.)

Comment: @ace, Answer is correct. It is using the fact that ascii value of '0' is '0x30' and that of '1' is '0x31', which can be anded or orred to get the similar result. (though `xor` would not be possible.)

Comment: Ah, yes. The point was to `AND`, one character at a time and do the assignment. In haste, I missed. Sorry for that :)